# Which optimizer to use in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to fit the Nelson-Siegel-Svensson model:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-income_attribution

The full model is non-linear, however in the simpler but analogous Nelson-Siegel model the original authors noted that conditional on a choice for tau the problem becomes linear. Indeed it's simply OLS.

For the Nelson Siegel and Svensson model I have two tau values, but the logic remains the same, conditional on the choice of two candidate lambdas the problem becomes linear.

The idea then is simply to search through the set of lambda pairs to find the one that produces the best overall fit.

Given this scenario, which Matlab optimizer should I use to solve it?
I think lsqcurvefit but I'm not sure?

Baz

Comment: I've done this before using lsqcurvefit (to find all 6 parameters). But watch out, if you don't have enough data points you could easily have an overfitting problem. Also it is very sensitive to initial conditions. I would suggest you add a regularization term to your cost functions to keep your parameters small (especially the lambdas)

Comment: It sounds like the problem is not finding the right way to implement a solution, but more finding the solution that makes most sense. For this you may be better of at crosvalidated.